# Silent install Sync Framework 2.1

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework, silent-installer

i want to silent install Sync Framework 2.1 because i put the redistributable package at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19502 to my setup installation package.

Can any1 help? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at bootstrapping here: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/syncdevdiscussions/thread/fd0a494f-cc12-435f-9d1e-5b74a893fdca

Comment: Hi JuneT, have a look at your comment in that thread a few days ago but i still can't find a best solution for this. Currently, i am using InnoSetup to create installation package :)